# Get Address when click on Marker - Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I need some help.
I loaded some point from database and displayed them on Google Maps as markers.
My code:

```
function DisplayTraficCir(points) {
  for (i=0;i<points.length;i++){
    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(points[i].latitude,points[i].longitude)
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatLng,
      map: map
    });
  }
}
```

And now, I want to get point's information (latitude/longitude) when I click on one of these markers in Google Maps to do some stuff.
Any help, please.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `google.maps.event.addListener` method:

```
function DisplayTraficCir(points) {
  for (i=0;i<points.length;i++){
    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(points[i].latitude,points[i].longitude)
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatLng,
      map: map
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
        var lng = points[i].longitue,
            lat = points[i].latitude;
        alert( lat + "-" + lng );
    });
  }
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/arcm111/jSDtp/)

Comment: But, when click in any marker in maps, the alert is the same. It's value is the lat and lng of the last point.

Comment: Ok. I done. Just put "google.maps.event.addListener" method in a function and call it in "for" statement. Thanks for your help!

Comment: if you want to use `marke.getPosition()` method in for loop use `this.getPosition()` instead so that it will select the relevant marker on each click, i updated my demo check it for more details.

Answer (score 0):

While razzak's approach will work, I'd like to suggest an alternative:

```
function DisplayTraficCir( points ) {
    for( var i = 0;  i < points.length;  i++ ) {
        DisplayTraficPoint( points[i] );
    }
}

function DisplayTraficPoint( point ) {
    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng( point.latitude, point.longitude );
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatLng,
        map: map
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener( marker, 'click', function() {
        alert( point.latitude + "-" + point.longitude );
    });
}
```

By simply moving the loop body into a function of its own, the code now captures the variables inside that function uniquely each time the function is called. That is, the `point` variable refers to the specific `points[i]` value that it was called with. Similarly, `myLatLng` and `marker` are unique to each time this function is called.

This gives you a very flexible and powerful way to keep track of any other data that you may associate with a marker: just make that data a local variable inside `DisplayTraficPoint()`.

Answer (score 0):

Just Call graphAddress() function when you click on marker.

```
function graphAddress(){
    geocoder.geocode({'latLng': marker_wizard.getPosition()}, function(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    if (results[0]) {
                            var address = results[0].formatted_address.split(",");
                            var country = address[address.length -1];       
                            var cityname = address[address.length -3];                      
                            var state_zipcode = address[address.length -2].split(" ");
                            var state   = state_zipcode[1];
                            var zipcode = state_zipcode[2];
                            address = address.splice(0,(address.length -3));
                      }
                }
        });
} //graphAddress
```

**NOTE : 
marker_wizard is the variable name of marker.**